# Quick Suggestion on VsCode

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, intellisense

A couple of days ago I could write 'fun' abbreviation to create a function statement line below.

[image]

[image]

But somehow, I cant find this abbreviation now on intellisense. Do you have any idea about what happened?

[image]

Comment: check your language mode https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_language-identifier

Comment: Already, dart lang is in use. That doesnt solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/4017

They will fix this issue soon.